# Google Material Icons alignment in Bootstrap buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design

How can I get Google Material Icons properly aligned in my Bootstrap buttons?

For example, consider this code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!-- body -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
  <span class="material-icons">delete</span> Supprimer
</button>
```

Gives me this output:

[image]

That is not very nice output. What is the best solution to fix the alignment between the icon and the text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Bootstrap class :

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary d-flex justify-content-center align-content-between" (click)="refresh()" [disabled]="loading">
     <i class="material-icons mr-1">refresh</i> <span>Refresh</span>
 </button>
```

Comment: `d-flex`: This code causes line breaks. `d-inline-flex` solve the problem.

Answer (score 10):

I use this.

It works for every button-size and icon-size. No additional classes nor elements and no flexbox. `line-height: 0;` prevents that the icon affects the height of the button.

```css
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!-- body -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
  <span class="material-icons">delete</span> Supprimer
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
  <span class="material-icons">delete</span> Supprimer
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
  <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 36px;">delete</span> Supprimer
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">
  <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 12px;">delete</span> Supprimer
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (inline styles on the button)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!-- body -->
<button style="display: flex;align-items: center;padding:5px 10px;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
  <span class="material-icons">delete</span> Supprimer
</button>
```

but I'd imagine there is a better way. This is just the first thing that springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Hope this helps....

```
button i.material-icons {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-right: 2px groove;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    Delete Item
</button>
```

Comment: Glad you found it useful @algorix.  Please do acknowledge it as your approved answer, to help others find it also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since I use `@material-ui/icons` in react I slightly modified the CSS fix to:

```
/*
 Align icons in buttons
 Prevent change of button height
 */
button svg {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}
```

Usage:

```
import {Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

<Button variant={"danger"}><CloseIcon fontSize={"small"}/>Close</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If used BS5

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light flex  align-middle d-inline-flex">  
               <i class="material-icons align-self-center">build</i>  
               Report & Dashbord
</button>
```